# yum in linux not working

Tags: linux, passenger, yum

I try to install passenger in my linux. And, when I use

```
yum update
```

Response is

```
Loaded plugins: priorities, security, update-motd, upgrade-helper
amzn-main                                                         | 2.1 kB     00:00     
amzn-main/primary_db                                              | 2.4 MB     00:00     
amzn-updates                                                      | 2.3 kB     00:00     
amzn-updates/primary_db                                           | 700 kB     00:00     
http://passenger.stealthymonkeys.com/rhel/latest/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
http://passenger.stealthymonkeys.com/rhel/latest/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
http://mirror.hmdc.harvard.edu/mirrors/passenger/rhel/latest/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: passenger. Please verify its path and try again
```

It is so weird, what happened to my linux?

Yes, the server is redhat.

Comment: More system info please?

Comment: Yes, the server is redhat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From bigrigdriver on [linuxquestions](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/package-kit-error-cannot-retrieve-repository-metadata-repomd-xml-for-repository-644682/)

> The error is probably in your /etc/yum.conf, or in
>   /etc/yum.repos.d/.repos. If the repo address goes one directory level
>   too deep (to the repodata folder) you will get that error.
>
> Copy the url in your repo file and paste in into a browser. It should
>   take you to the repository site. It if ends up in the repodata folder
>   (where the repmod.xml file is located), back off one level in the
>   directory tree so that you see a tree with folders like: i585 i686
>   noarch ppc repodata x86_64
>
> That should be the last level in the repo url. Yum will find the
>   repodata folder and repmod.xml, and apply the necessary data for you
>   installation (either 32 bit or 64 bit).

Comment: I come to /etc/yum.repos.d/, and delete passenger.repo. Then, everything is fine. Thank you!

Comment: deleting passenger.repo worked for me as well.

Answer (score 2):

`http://passenger.stealthymonkeys.com/rhel/latest` does not exist. This means your Yum configuration is out of date.

You can edit `/etc/yum.repos.d/...` to replace `latest` with `6rolling`. Or you can try re-installing the `passenger-release.noarch.rpm` from http://passenger.stealthymonkeys.com/ which will likely do it for you.